# Electron: Keep Getting 'You'll need a new app to open this' Screen

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Developed an Electron app using Vuejs and everything works fine in development, but when packaged I keep getting this pop-up after start up (**NOTE**: This is a sample image - mine doesn't say 'windowsdefender' but is otherwise the same).

[image: Sample pop-up after running electron app]

Using electron-builder to create the application with the following build json, and it is installed on the PC:

```
{
  "productName": "My App",
  "appId": "com.mycompany.myapp",
  "win": {
    "icon": "build/icon.png",
    "target": [
      "nsis"
    ]
  }
}
```

Though the app does open, there is no initial screen. However, I can open the dev tools but there are no errors displayed.

Any ideas on what is causing this or how to resolve?

Comment: if you give your file an .exe extension, does it run? I'm guessing something in the builder would need to be configured to create an exe file (Assuming Windows). I personally use the electron-packager and it spits out an exe

Comment: from a little searching, this is intended to spit out an installer, right? Does running the installer cause this problem, or does running the actual app that's installed cause this issue

Comment: @pushkin Thanks for your reply. The generated files include an exe that installs on Windows fine. The pop up comes when the application starts.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, I finally figured it out (or at least I think I know what caused the issue).

The primary issue was that in using vue router (from an app ported from the web), it is important that you use 'hash' mode and not 'history. Add this to your router file:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: process.env.IS_ELECTRON ? "hash" : "history",
  routes
});
```

See this link for more details (common issues): [Vue CLI plugin common issues](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/commonIssues.html#blank-screen-on-builds-but-works-fine-on-serve)

Second, I think there is a rights issue (i.e. having elevated rights to install) so I added this line along with the guid to my electron-builder.json file. The result was a build file like this:

```
{
  "productName": "My App",
  "appId": "com.abcco.my-app",
  "win": {
    "icon": "build/icon.png",
    "target": "nsis",
    "requestedExecutionLevel": "requireAdministrator"
  },
  "nsis": {
    "guid": "6ee647a9-d5c6-46a9-a480-aa7d6d3d1c10",
    "oneClick": false,
    "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
  }
}
```

As I am developing only for Windows I was able to use material from this page (React but not that different with respect to Electron packaging):

[Electron Build file help](https://www.edwardbeazer.com/run-electron-applications-with-admin-privileges-in-windows/)

The last thing I did was to remove all 'dist' files and uninstall the app entirely (previous versions). I think this cleared up a lot of the 'baggage' left over from testing.

Hopefully this helps others who may experience the same issue.